# MySQL chain replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I have 3 servers A, B and C. What I want to do is replicate databases like this A->B->C, where A is replicating DB1 and DB2 to B and B is replicating those same databases to C, but I would also like to add an additional database from B that will replicated to C.

In other words, I want to replicate databases like this:

```
A (DB1, DB2) -> B (DB1, DB2) + DB3 -> C (DB1, DB2, DB3)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes

ServerB will just replicate *all* databases to ServerC (ignoring [replicate-ignore-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-ignore-db) for now). There is no setting that limits ServerC to getting data that exists only on ServerA

That is,  `A(master) ->B (slave)` is unrelated to `B(master) -> C(slave)` and A and C have no knowledge or replication dependency on each other